# Calculating The Limit Of $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{k=1}^n\:\frac{k}{k^2+n^2}\right)$

Tags: integration, limits

Hello everyone how can I calculate the limit of : 
$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{k=1}^n\:\frac{k}{k^2+n^2}\right)$
By using Riemann sum?

Comment: Note that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k^2+n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{k/n}{1+(k/n)^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Divide the numerator and denominator by $n^2$:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\frac{k}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{k^2}{n^2}+1}$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2+1} \; dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln{|x^2+1|} \bigg \rvert_0^1$$
$$=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\ln{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!!